# How can i print a void method that iterates through a LinkedList

Tags: java

I'm creating a class that monitors the price, address and number of bedrooms within a house. I'm trying to call the result for my `twoBeds` method. Pretty sure my `Sysout` is completely wrong but I dont know where to start.

```
public class House {

    int price;
    int bedrooms;
    String address;

    public House(int a, int b, String c) {
        price = a;
        bedrooms = b;
        address = c;
    }

    static List<House> agency = new LinkedList<House>();

    public static int noHouse() {
        return agency.size();
    }

    public static void twoBeds() {
        for (ListIterator<House> it = agency.listIterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
            House h = it.next();
            if (h.bedrooms == 2) {
                System.out.println(h.address);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        House h1 = new House(12, 2, "address");
        agency.add(h1);
        System.out.println(twoBeds());
    }
}
```

Comment: remove the call to `println`

Comment: Remove System.out.println out of twoBeds() call in main method, because you already have printing inside the twoBeds() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.out.println()` accepts a parameter, `void` return type means that there is nothing to return.

You need to return something to print it.

**Option 1:** Do not pass void function in `System.out`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    House h1 = new House(12, 2, "address");
    agency.add(h1);
    twoBeds();
}
```

**Option 2:** Change return type of `twoBeds()`:

```
public static List<String> twoBeds() {
    List<String> matchedAddresses = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ListIterator<House> it = agency.listIterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
        House h = it.next();
        if (h.bedrooms == 2) {
            matchedAddresses.add(h.address);
        }
    }
    return matchedAddresses;
}
```

Comment: Your second example assumes there’s only one house with two bedrooms in inventory. You may want to change return type to List<House>, and filter inventory (as a stream?) in the method. The calling function decides how to print the returned values, perhaps using a separate procedure to do so.

Comment: @Timir makes sence, fixed. There is much to refactor actually in OP code, but I'm not sure if he need to do it. Maybe it's better to stick the approach he already has.